# the existence of compact Kahler manifolds satisfying some Hodge numbers' restrictions

Tags: complex-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, ag.algebraic-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Given any $n\geq 2$, is there an example of $n$-dimensional compact Kahler manifold such that its Hodge numbers satisfy $h^{1,1} = h^{2,2} < h^{3,3} = h^{4,4} < h^{5,5} = h^{6,6} < \cdots h^{[\frac{n}{2}],[\frac{n}{2}]}$.

Note that 2-plane complex Grassmannian's Hodge numbers satisfy $h^{0,0} = h^{1,1} < h^{2,2} = h^{3,3} < h^{4,4} = h^{5,5} < h^{6,6}=\cdots h^{[\frac{n}{2}],[\frac{n}{2}]}$.

Comment: $h^{1,1}=h^{2,2}<h^{3,3}=h^{4,4}<h^{5,5}=h^{6,6}<$

$h^{0,0}=h^{1,1}<h^{2,2}=h^{3,3}<h^{4,4}=h^{5,5}<h^{6,6}=\cdots.$

Comment: So strange! I don't why in the main text the two above formulae cannot be exhibited regularly and completely. So I give the formulae in the above comments. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry. The correct two formulas is as follows.
$$h^{1,1}=h^{2,2}<h^{3,3}=h^{4,4}<h^{5,5}=h^{6,6}<\cdots.$$
$$h^{0,0}=h^{1,1}<h^{2,2}=h^{3,3}<h^{4,4}=h^{5,5}<h^{6,6}=\cdots.$$

Comment: The formulae don't display because you've only got one '$' symbol. You should have one at the beginning and one at the end of the formulae.

Comment: @Michael Albanese I am sure I used the correct symbols as this is not my first time to ask questions. But I really do not know why the expressions are as above.:-)

Comment: @Ping Li: I put in some spaces which fixed the rendering problem.

Comment: @Ping Li: When I saw this question originally, it just displayed $h^{1,1}=h^{2,2}, hence my comment. Not sure if that is what you typed in at your end. Sorry if my comment seemed condescending. 

Comment: Exactly up to which value of $p$ do you want $h^{p,p}$ to increase? By the Hodge symmetry, it cannot increase until $p=n$!

Comment: Say we start with $X=\mathbb{P}^n$. What happens to the Hodge diamond if we blow up a $p$-dimensional linear subspace?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: this answer refers to a previous version of the question.

Already for $n=3$ the answer is no. Indeed, $h^{3,3}=1$ so by your condition $h^{1,1}=h^{2,2}=0$ but
a compact Kähler manifold has $h^{1,1}>0$.

Comment: Sorry. You misunderstand my meaning. The sequence in my question should stop at $h^{[\frac{n}{2}],[\frac{n}{2}]}$. Otherwise this question is clearly makes no sense.

Comment: I know, my answer was meant to show you that you should put a bit more effort in writing your questions correctly!

Comment: @YangMills: Thanks. I have modified my original question.

Comment: Your modified question is trivial for $n<6$, since in that case $\mathbb{CP}^n$ works.

Comment: @YangMills: Of course. But obviously I want to know whether or not there exist examples for all $n$.